# How is a flag disputed?

Tags: support

Recently I raised a flag on meta.Phys.SE. Practically the flag was declined, that is no action was taken by the moderators. But the strange thing is that it is not declined officially. It is marked as **disputed**. What does it mean? I don't want to know about this particular flag. I want to know about this in general i.e. how are and why some flags disputed? Can flags on the main site too be disputed?

Comment: Definition of disputed: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4737/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/

Comment: It means that a 10k user marked it as invalid.

Comment: @Manishearth you said there:"It basically means that non mods disagreed on the flag." If this is the meaning of disputed flag then why not any action was taken on my flag?

Comment: @Anupam Because the mods did not feel that it needed action. Read the decline reason, a disputed flag can either have been marked as helpful or declined by the mods.

Comment: Also a duplicate: [Flags marked "helpful" but question not closed?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4443)